# Rhetorical strategy by collecting many agreeing individual perspectives to prove something right/wrong

Tags: rhetorical-devices

I believe there is a specific rhetorical strategy by using large number of agreeing perspectives to prove the author's point (e.g. Person A said...Person B also stated...Company C explained)

The closest I can think of is testimony but I can't guarantee that as the strategy I'm looking for.

Can anyone clarify? Thanks!

Comment: It depends what exactly you are trying to say.  What it is not is any sort “proof”.  Such arguments are presented for rhetorical purposes as proofs or at least as evidence,  but are nothing of the kind.  So Greybeard is right to describe it as a kind of ‘appeal’. What you have might be an appeal to public opinion.  “The government policy must be right:  polling shows it an approval rating of 60%.”.  You can appeal to authority.  “Our Covid-19 policy is correct because it follows the scientific advice.”.  That is at least defensible up to a point.  But:  “It must be true: I read it on Twitter”?

Comment: *Compaigning*? *Brigading*?

Answer (score 2):

The strategy of using large numbers to demonstrate the truth of a proposition is a fallacy known as **"[appeal to popularity](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Appeal-to-Popularity)"**.  In strict terms, merely because ten million people say that, for example, walking under a ladder will bring bad luck, does not mean that it is true.

Comment: My favorite example of this is in Kipling's _bandar-log_ road-song:  _We are great. We are free. We are wonderful. We are the most wonderful people in all the jungle! We all say so, and so it must be true._